# PHP breaking URL by encoding ampersand

Tags: php, url, encode

I'm debugging a site where this code is intended to display in image:

```
<a href="<?=$auction_link;?>"><img src="<? echo ((!empty($main_image)) ? 'thumbnail.php?pic=' . $main_image . '&w=' . $layout['hpfeat_width'] . '&sq=Y' : 'themes/' . $setts['default_theme'] . '/img/system/noimg.gif');?>" border="0" alt="<?=$item_details[$counter]['name'];?>"></a>
```

No image is displayed, evidently because the href value is being converted to:

```
thumbnail.php?pic=uplimg/img_A_100430_b93204949c62ffba35eb62f1b94b93c4.jpg&amp;w=0&amp;sq=Y"
```

When it should be:

```
thumbnail.php?pic=uplimg/img_A_100430_b93204949c62ffba35eb62f1b94b93c4.jpg&w=250&sq=Y
```

Note the `&amp;` where the & should be in two places. Is there anyway to stop the encoding?

Thanks - Joe

Comment: PHP does not do things you don't ask it to. Somewhere you are escaping the URL value, likely with `htmlspecialchars()`.

Comment: Although it's encoded it should work, because it must be encoded. In HTML the & may only be used for entity-references(it usually works with both variants, but without the encoding it's invalid HTML). The issue must be something else.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `&amp;` in your PHP source.  PHP does not encode the ampersand by the way.

```
/*...*/ $main_image . '&amp;w=' . $layout['hpfeat_width'] . '&amp;sq=Y' /*...*/
```

Comment: Yeah it was a long shot because in reality either one should work.  This just proves that something else is wrong.  What browser and version are you using? What sort of meta tags do you have? etc etc. you need to put as much information as possible in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You are encoding for HTML instead of for URLS.

If you want the ampersand to be data rather than control - that is, if you want the ampersand passed to the server as part of a parameter name or value rather than as a separator betweek key-value pairs, you want to use %xx encoding, where xx is the hexadecimal value of the character you want to encode.

If you don't want it encoded at all, you need to find the code that's doing the encoding snd remove it (nothing happens by magic).

Comment: The url is in html so why shouldn't it be html encoded.

Comment: Because the context is different. URLs are parsed differently, and are defined in a different standard than HTML is.

Comment: I do want it to be a separator, and this is the way I would normally do it. But you're right - there does seem to be some other function doing the encoding. I was trying to find a way to work around that.